# NVD3 arcTween func throwing undefined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3 1.8.1 with D3 3.5.6.

I have a weird issue where for some reason (roughly 5-10% of the time) my graph doesn't load.

The error is "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" thrown by the arcTween function (for piechart) in nv.d3.js:

```
function arcTween(a, idx) {
            a.endAngle = isNaN(a.endAngle) ? 0 : a.endAngle;
            a.startAngle = isNaN(a.startAngle) ? 0 : a.startAngle;
            if (!donut) a.innerRadius = 0;
            var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function (t) {
                return arcs[idx](i(t));
            };
        }
```

When debugging, I can see the values are all over the place, i.e. idx appears to be a reference to the whole nvd3 library rather than an integer! 'i' is a number not a function, this._current is undefined etc.

If I refresh the page it breaks on average probably 5-10% of the time. Other than that it all works fine and as expected.

I created a codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbVpme), but can't replicate the issue there unfortunately... I should probably mention this is all contained within an angular directive and generated off the 'element' that angular passes in when creating the directive.

Given that I can only recreate it in my code intermittently, I know it must be something going wrong with my code but I cannot figure it out so as a last resort thought I'd post the question here.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Any suggestions to work around the issue? I was thinking something like checking if the graph has been generated correctly otherwise try to render it again but it's annoying not to find the root cause.

I'd be grateful for any advice,

Sam

EDIT:

Also, the chart partially generates, just the 'path' is missing for each 'slice':

```
<svg class="_pie1 nvd3-svg"><g class="nvd3 nv-wrap nv-pieChart" transform="translate(20,30)"><g><g class="nv-pieWrap nvd3-svg"><g class="nvd3 nv-wrap nv-pie nv-chart-2110" transform="translate(0,0)"><g><g class="nv-pie" transform="translate(177.5,172.5)"><g class="nv-slice" fill="#00385D" stroke="#00385D"><path></path></g><g class="nv-slice" fill="transparent" stroke="transparent"><path></path></g></g><g class="nv-pieLabels" transform="translate(177.5,172.5)"></g></g></g></g><g class="nv-legendWrap"></g></g></g><text x="195" y="180" dy="-.7em" class="nv-title" style="text-anchor: middle;">Total income*</text><text x="195" y="210" dy="-.7em" class="nv-titleValue" style="text-anchor: middle;">£4,543</text><line x1="130" y1="205" x2="265" y2="205" stroke-width="0.1" stroke="#333333"></line><text x="195" y="245" dy="-.7em" class="nv-title" style="text-anchor: middle;">Total outgoings</text><text x="195" y="275" dy="-.7em" class="nv-titleValue" style="text-anchor: middle;">£46,574</text></svg>
```

EDIT again: If I remove the 50ms timeout (see codepen) I get the error every time so there's some timing issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. Basically we were creating the piecharts with values of 1, then changing this to the actual values, so we could get a nice nvd3 transition (as nvd3 doesn't animate if the graph loads with actual values, it's only when you change them).

We had a timeout of 50ms which was intended to wait for the page to visibly load (we have a fade in animation) so the piechart animation was visible to the user on page load but this was actually masking the issue of setting the chart values twice in quick succession (to 1, and then to actual values) which was causing the issue. Obviously the graph needed longer than 50ms to render occasionally and so we got the intermittent error.

Comment: glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score -1):

```
return arcs[idx](i(t));
```

That looks like an unintended function call which might be causing your error?

If you're looking to do some multiplication there, then I suggest explicitly using a asterisk (*).

e.g.

```
return arcs[idx] * (i(t));
```

Comment: Hi @DubstepCat, that is correct that that line throws the error. It is a function coming from the nvd3 library. I changed it as you suggested but this caused the graph to never generate and throw an error every time (Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="NaN"). Thanks for your prompt help